# Spring Boot junit5 tests working locally (Windows) but not in Jenkins (Linux)

Tags: spring-boot, jenkins, junit5

I'm going to answer my own question here in case it is useful for anyone else...

After updating to Spring Boot 2.4.0 (from 2.3.4), and to JUnit5 (from JUnit4), my unit tests started failing on Jenkins. The strange thing was that they were working locally.

This was in the error log on Jenkins:

```
Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [my.PackageName.controller.ControllerTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
```

Why have the tests stopped working on Jenkins but are fine locally?

I found similar questions / answers on SO, but not my specific issue... (apologies if the answer is already out there)

Answer (score 0):

It took me too long to spot it, but the key is:

```
Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [my.**PackageName**.controller.ControllerTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
```

`PackageName` is in camel case. For some reason, a long time ago, when I created my test classes I put them in the package:

```
package my.PackageName.controller;
```

And the fix is to change this to:

```
package my.packagename.controller;
```

Because the Linux file system is case sensitive, and Windows is not. And the updates to the dependencies seems to have changed the way packages are resolved somewhere.